# Efficient loading of pictures using OpenGL

Tags: android, opengl-es

I am developing a 2D game for android using lots of sprites. I am drawing on the screen using OpenGL ES. I separeted the sprites into several pictures (around 7). I read, that loading a picture into memory takes most of the time. Every picture contains a diffrent category of images: for example - background elements, enemy units, etc, etc. I load them in a defined order: background picture first, so background elements are drawn at the bottom, then the enemy units, etc. But what should I do, if I want to draw elements of the background at the top of the canvas. Should I load the picture with background elements twice? Or store that special element in both pictures - the background picture and the picture containg top elements. Or there is a better way? Thanks!

Comment: (correct me if im wrong) i dont think it matters in which order you load the images to the GPU memory, just that in which order you use them: its more efficient to bind/use one huge texture than multiple small textures. so my suggestion would be to try to fit most of the sprites into one big texture atlas.

Comment: Yes, thats true, but I'm targetting old devices too, like my HTC Hero for example. It can load images with largest size of 1024x512. Everything bigger slows it down a lot (I tried). And I have a lot of sprites, maybe three pictures 2048x2048 will be enough to fit everything in, but it won't run on old devices :)

Comment: are you loading the pictures (to GPU from image file) every rendered frame...? thats how it sounded from your original question.

Comment: no, i load them only at the start of the game and store everyone of them in a separate instance of a class. Every frame I bind every picture to the instance of gl (I think this is a kind of state change).

Comment: i can think of few things: 1) disable mipmapping (if its enabled at all), saves memory. 2) use smaller textures for those older devices, thats how usually games are made: you can choose which quality textures they use. 3) be sure to disable anisotropic (should be default off) filtering and stuff like that which makes rendering a lot slower. 4) figure out the maximum texture size of the platform where its run from and store textures according to that size limits (create texture atlas). 5) disable blending for sprites(possibly the background image) that doesnt have transparency(faster rendering)

Comment: thanks for the advices, i will try to follow them :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loading has nothing to do with rendering. As long as you render something *after* you've loaded it, then you're fine. The order that things get rendered in is not affected by the order you loaded them in.

Now, if it's an issue of memory (ie: you can't load everything at once), then the steps you need to take depend *greatly* on exactly what you're doing. We can't really give you anything more than general advice, because we don't know everything about what you're doing.

In general, you need to break down your rendered world into chunks that fit in memory. This will put constraints on your *design*: you can't use stuff (be it backgrounds, enemy units, whatever) from outside of that chunk. Since you're developing on limited platforms, you're just going to have to put up with those constraints.